# Controller Action method is not triggered on succeeding calls for the same parameter using jquery load

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am loading a div using the below statement.

```
$("#dialog").load('/Home/MyActionMethod?id=' + id);
```

The above statement perfectly calls the corresponding Action Method, Let us say id = 1
When I call this statement again with the parameter id = 1, it doesn't trigger the data Action method in my controller. But if my value of id is changed (if id is 2 or 3), it triggers the event perfectly.

I want my controller to be called everytime irrespective of id.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options, turn off the caching globally

```
// make sure this is called before any of your ajax call is called
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of ajax responses
    cache: false
});
```

or use the longer form of `load`

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/MyActionMethod?id=' + id,
    cache: false
});
```

Comment: Though my problem was different but I got my solution here... url: '/.... Wish I could upvote more than once.